# Testing of URL evaluator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to write a Unit Test in Visual Studio 2019 for this method:

```
      public static string ReplaceUrls(this string text, UrlEvaluator evaluator) {
     var matches = UrlPrefix.Matches(text);
     if (matches.Count == 0) {
        return text;
     }
```

My test should look something like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReplaceUrlsTest()
    {
        public delegate string UrlEvaluator(string url);
        string t = "https://web.whatsapp.com/";
        UrlEvaluator evaluator;
        string expectedResult = "< URL Delete >"; 
        string actualResult = Utility.ReplaceUrls(t,evaluator);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
```

but it doesn't work like that. Visual Studio underlines the `string actualResult =`  line and shows the following error:

> Error CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'UtilityTest.evaluator'

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What does _"but it doesn't work like that"_ mean exactly?

Comment: it underlines the actual result line declaration line. i seem to call the method incorrectly.

Comment: And what does Visual Studio tell you is the problem?

Comment: Error CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'UtilityTest.evaluator'

Comment: Surely `UrlEvaluator` is already defined somewhere else? I don't think you've provided enough context for your `ReplaceUrls` method.